# Ubuntu 14.10 crashes without apparent cause

Tags: 14.10, crash

I bought a Lenovo G50-45 notebook. I installed 14.04 and then updated to 14.10. When I try to play flash games in Facebook (I'm using Firefox) the game starts, even the level starts but then Ubuntu hangs after a short time and only a reset helps. The flash is 11.2.202.425.
Somebody please help me get rid of the problem.

Edit 1:
Apparently the cause is not flash. I just had another crash, when trying to read a plain html page in Opera. I have no idea, how to go about identifying the root cause.